# Adding Names to columns in a matrix

Tags: reporting-services

I have my matrix I have created, a pic found here.

http://s816.photobucket.com/albums/zz83/gavakie/?action=view&current=matrix.jpg

The first three column what whats being grouped by but I can had the names of those columns, how can I do that in Reporting Services?

Answer (score 0):

you must add your field name to each record in your query and use from this field as Column field.